# Delphi - (x,y) position of finger on laptop touchpad

Tags: delphi, winapi, touchpad

I'm trying to get the position of finger on laptop touchpad in Delphi. Not the position of cursor on screen. So I can use it for drawing purposes. Is this possible? How can I do this? Is there any Windows API or any component for this?

Thanks for your help.

### Update

I found a software for Lenovo touchpad that does the exact thing. It only shows the position of fingers on touchpad and PEiD says it's been written with Visual C++. So I guess it's a possible thing but as [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089337/delphi-x-y-position-of-finger-on-laptop-touchpad#comment40882174_26089337) said it depends on manufacturer of the touchpad and it's hardware specific.

[image]

Comment: I'd expect any such functionality to require hardware specific driver use.

Comment: See [Dr.Bob Examines... #116](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinB6.htm) about the Touch and Gestures support by Delphi. And also [Delphi 2010 Tablet PC Support](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4303115/576719).

Answer (score 4):

Coincidentally, I've just spent the last 30 minutes researching this very thing.

Windows supports this through the [touch and gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336016.aspx) APIs.  These were introduced in Windows 7 but touchpad drivers didn't tend to offer the necessary support until Windows 8 arrived and made it a logo requirement.

Synaptics and Alps seem to be the principal touchpad manufacturers and they have both released updated drivers for Windows 8 which also work on Windows 7.  "Multitouch" is the keyword to search for.  This is touchpad-model dependent though; I can't find an update for older Alps devices.

In short, this should work on a "Designed for Windows 8" laptop.  It may work on Windows 7 and if it doesn't you may be able to get an updated driver.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is generally no, this is not possible.  Touchpad drivers present to the operating system such that they appear and behave like a mouse does.  Absolute coordinates are not available.  For this application you need a proper touchscreen device or tablet, at least if you are looking for a general solution that is supported by the operating system.

Some touchpads may provide this information through a hardware-specific driver, of course, but you would need to support, where this is even an option, each device independently.  Synaptics, for example, [provides an SDK](http://www.synaptics.com/en/developers.php#info_content) and drivers that can expose the absolute coordinate information.

For tablets or other full-screen digitizers that are supported as *"Pen and Touch"* inputs, this information is usally obtained through the [`WM_TOUCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  Some advanced touchpads may support this - you can always query to discover what features are supported.  For those that are, you have to register your application's window to recieve touch messages as detailed here :

[Getting Started with Windows Touch Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Upon receiving a [`WM_TOUCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message you can obtain detailed information by immediately passing the touch handle to [`GetTouchInputInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Which returns an array of [`TOUCHINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures, each carrying information about each active touch point on the digitizer surface.